# Mosquitto and JavaScript Example not working (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, ssl, firefox, mosquitto

I would like to make a Websocket connection with TLS encryption to my mosquitto server. But I do not even get a simple example with the official mosquitto server running.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Hello MQTT World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize a mqtt variable globally
    console.log(mqtt)


// connection option
const options = {
        clean: true, // retain session
      connectTimeout: 4000, // Timeout period
      // Authentication information
      clientId: 'test_client',
}

// Connect string, and specify the connection method by the protocol
// ws Unencrypted WebSocket connection
// wss Encrypted WebSocket connection
// mqtt Unencrypted TCP connection
// mqtts Encrypted TCP connection
// wxs WeChat applet connection
// alis Alipay applet connection
const connectUrl = 'wss://test.mosquitto.org:8081/mqtt'
const client = mqtt.connect(connectUrl,options)

client.on('reconnect', (error) => {
    console.log('reconnecting:', error)
})

client.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('Connection failed:', error)
})

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
  console.log('receive message：', topic, message.toString())
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logger"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the network Log I can see these statements:

```
...
[1]</</</v.prototype._setupReconnect
https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js:1:14126
[1]</</</v.prototype._cleanUp
https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js:1:15261
[1]</</</v.prototype._setupStream/this.connackTimer<
https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js:1:7007
(Async: setTimeout handler) [1]</</</v.prototype._setupStream
https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js:1:6920
[1]</</</v.prototype._reconnect
https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js:1:13732
[1]</</</v.prototype._setupReconnect/e.reconnectTimer<
https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js:1:14195
(Async: setInterval handler)
...
```

Firefox (Mozilla Firefox for Linux Mint 89.0 (64-bit)) gives the error message *Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://test.mosquitto.org:8081/mqtt.*

Maybe somebody can give me a hint what's wrong with my setup? Or a know working JavaScript example?

Thanks in advance,
Christof

Comment: It looks like the websocket interface on test.mosquitto.org is not doing so well at the moment, I suggest you try again tomorrow or try a different example server (e.g. hivemq's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First increase the connection timeout, you currently have it set to 4 seconds, the default is 30 seconds. Because test.mosquitto.org is a totally public broker it often gets hammered by people (either testing stuff or just not thinking what they are doing) so a longer timeout is better.

Secondly, having a clientID of `test_client` is VERY likely to clash with another client so your client will get kicked off the broker as soon as the other client tries to reconnect which will cause your client to reconnect causing a connect/disconnect loop. ClientID's need to unique across ALL clients connecting to the broker, I suggest you change this to a unique to you prefix combined with a random number.

Thirdly you don't actually do anything even if you connect, you make no subscriptions, so the on `message` event handler will never be called. You don't even have a on `connect` event handler to know if you ever get connected cleanly.

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Hello MQTT World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize a mqtt variable globally
    console.log(mqtt)


// connection option
const options = {
        clean: true, // retain session
      connectTimeout: 30000, // Timeout period increased to 30 seconds
      // Authentication information
      clientId: 'foobar_test_random' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
}

// Connect string, and specify the connection method by the protocol
// ws Unencrypted WebSocket connection
// wss Encrypted WebSocket connection
// mqtt Unencrypted TCP connection
// mqtts Encrypted TCP connection
// wxs WeChat applet connection
// alis Alipay applet connection
const connectUrl = 'wss://test.mosquitto.org:8081'
const client = mqtt.connect(connectUrl,options)

//actually subscribe to something on a sucessfull connection
client.on('connect', (connack) => {
  client.subscribe('$SYS/#')
})

client.on('reconnect', (error) => {
    console.log('reconnecting:', error)
})

client.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('Connection failed:', error)
})

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
  console.log('receive message：', topic, message.toString())
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logger"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the meantime I changed the browser to Chromium and there it works. I did manage to get the subscription and attach this to an HTML element. But I would like to get JSON data and this is not working. With plain text it works.

Maybe you have another hint what I have to take care of?

Comment: an example of a message is
`
owntracks/user/galahad {"_type":"location","acc":15,"alt":630,"batt":56,"bs":1,"conn":"m","created_at":1630968608,"lat":45.8052892,"lon":12.5361642,"t":"u","tid":"ad","tst":1630968603,"vac":150,"vel":1}
`

Comment: In particular I'm interested in LAT an LON as well as the timestamp "created_at"

Comment: It's appropriate to post a new question as a new post on Stack Overflow. That gives other people the chance to answer it, and makes it findable by people who have similar problems. They won't find it if it's posted as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll post a new question for the problem with JSON.

But I still do not know why Firefox isn't working, maybe there is an expert anywhere to answer this question

Answer (score 1):

If your implementation works on Chrome but not Firefox then you might run into the issue mentioned here: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1211. I ran into this issue as well with the same setup, eg Mosquitto v2 using Websockets over TLS. It connects fine on Chrome but Firefox does not accept a connection.

The problem this issue describes is that Mosquitto does not handle websockets over HTTP/2. More precisely, libwebsockets used by Mosquitto uses HTTP/2.
Chrome is using websockets over TLS which does work.

There are a few possible workarounds:

1. Find a Mosquitto package with HTTP/2 disabled in libwebsocket. This is by far the easiest solution. Interestingly, the last comment in the above issue is that:

> As of version 2.0.14, Debian packages from http://repo.mosquitto.org have this issue fixed.

The [changelog of version 2.0.14](https://mosquitto.org/blog/2021/11/version-2-0-14-released/) does not mention this issue so maybe the Debian package maintainer solved it by building with a libwebsocket that has HTTP/2 disabled.

2. Build your own Mosquitto with HTTP/2 disabled in libwebsocket.
3. Disable SPDY in firefox, so it uses HTTP/1.1. This might work during development but you can't expect all users to disable HTTP/2 in Firefox. It is however an easy way to confirm that you're dealing with this issue.

Update: Unfortunately, after installing Mosquitto 2.0.14 using the Ubuntu package ppa from https://mosquitto.org/download/  (scroll all the way to the bottom). The problem is still there.