# How to connect firebase hosting with wss mosquitto?

Tags: firebase, mqtt, wss, mqtt.js

I want to connect hosting firebase with wss mosquitto. Domain is `https://tkllhk231.web.app/`. I configured mosquitto.conf. Code is running in edge : `https://tkllhk231.web.app/`.

```
listener 8084
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous true
cafile C:/Program Files/mosquitto/Firebase/public/certificates/ca.crt
certfile C:/Program Files/mosquitto/Firebase/public/certificates/server.crt
keyfile C:/Program Files/mosquitto/Firebase/public/certificates/server.key
tls_version tlsv1
```

I've successfully connected using MQTTX over WSS, but I'm encountering issues connecting to Firebase hosting.
It my code:

```
function connectToBroker() {
  const clientId = "client" + Date.now();
  const host = "wss://172.20.107.226:8084/ws";
  
  const caPath = "/certificates/ca.crt";
  const certPath = "/certificates/server.crt";
  const keyPath = "/certificates/servver.key";

  // Fetch CA certificate
  fetch(caPath)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(ca => {
      // Fetch client certificate
      fetch(certPath)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(cert => {
          // Fetch private key
          fetch(keyPath)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(key => {
              const options = {
                keepalive: 60,
                clientId: clientId,
                protocolId: "MQTT",
                protocolVersion: 4,
                clean: true,
                reconnectPeriod: 1000,
                connectTimeout: 30 * 1000,
                ca: ca,
                cert: cert,
                key: key,
              };

              const mqttClient = mqtt.connect(host, options);
              mqttClient.on("error", (err) => {
                console.log("Error: ", err);
                mqttClient.end();
              });

              mqttClient.on("reconnect", () => {
                console.log("Reconnecting...");
              });

              mqttClient.on('connect', function () {
                console.log('Connect Successfully broker');
```

[I connect successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HED9z.png)

I have tried using MQTTX to connect to WSS, and it was successful. However, when attempting to use Firebase hosting, it is reconnect.

Comment: You appear to be trying to run this code in the users browser (based on a quick look at `https://tkllhk231.web.app/`). This will not work (you will be unable to access files on `C:\ `, `require` does not work in the browser, client certs will not work in browser, `<script src="https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js"></script>` will define `mqtt` etc). Please clarify if running this in the users browser is your intention, and provide details of what "is not working" means (error messages, logs etc). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69080739/11810946) may helpful.

Comment: I apologize for changing the source code during testing. The full source code is on my GitHub : https://github.com/ThongNguyen182003/MQTT_FIREBASE

Comment: I don't understand the const host = "wss://172.20.107.226:8084/ws"; line. Is the host address here the correct IPV4 address on my computer? I don't know how to set up the host address.

Comment: Please edit the question, removing any outdated info and adding extra details (e.g. where is the broker hosted, where is the code being run, what "not working means"). "I don't understand" the broker will need to be accessible from the client (`172.20.107.226` is a [private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) address, so is not accessible over the internet, but may be accessible within your WAN - more info is needed to respond further).

Comment: `172.20.107.226` is a private IP address. Can I switch it to some hosting so that Firebase can connect? For instance, can I change it to: `wss://broker.emqx.io/mqtt:8084?`

Comment: Yes; you can test using one of the publicly available test brokers (this would be a good first step as it eliminates a range of broker config issues and allows you to provide use with a reproducible example if your code does not work).